# Are there zombies in the Campaign?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I have just gotten Black Ops 2 and I'm wondering if you get zombies in the campaign or is zombies separate?

Answer (score 4):

There are no zombies in the campaign.

The Zombie mode is a separate (multiplayer) mode.

You can find more info here:

[IGN Black Ops 2 Zombies](http://www.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-black-ops-2/Zombies)